# Magento image upload error from Admin 1.9.2.3

Tags: image, upload

This question is regarding image upload problems in back-end only :

**Problem 1:**

I cannot Upload image from the Magento Admin panel(live sever) , some times im getting error:

```
SSL Error: Invalid or self-signed certificate
```

sometimes :

- No error upload progress halts between 50 - 100 %
- the image upload progress just halt at 100%
- Image uploads perfectly
- http error

Im uploading the image without any third party module/extension
i had found lot of questions regarding SSL error while googling.But none of this solved my problem.

I had changed permission of media,var & tmp folder(including sub folders) permission to 775.
The Same project is working perfectly on localhost.

**Problem 2:**

I cannot find the image preview for the images that are newly uploaded

After inspecting the source i found there is no image uploaded here:

```
 /media/tmp/catalog/product/h/a/some-image.jpg
```

But there is no issues with images on frontend

[image]

I believe that these two problem has some relation together. I had recently upgraded from 1.7

Comment: Magento is using a Flash object for the file uploader which blows chunks when it detects self-signed certificates, has to deal with .htaccess password protected development environments, or http server security certificate misconfigurations.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs im not using secure url. & does this aapplicable to http connection?

Comment: i still .. waiting for an answer :(